# Hide the Resize arrow in the form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

In my C# application I have set the form border to `Fixed3D`, as I don't want to re-size it. However, the arrow on the bottom right of the form still appears for re-size even though it doesn't allow re-sizing.

How do I hide that arrow?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this... Do you have a status bar or something added to the form?

Comment: Wasn't able to reproduce, Visual Studio 2010 .NET 4 Windows 7 - no arrow anywhere. What framework/OS you have?

Comment: @RQDQ, yes I have a status bar. I use VS 2008 .NET 3.5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My best guess is you have a StatusStrip on the form.  If so, set the [SizingGrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.statusbar.sizinggrip%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property to false.

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is:

```
this.SizeGripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle.Hide;
```

or it can be set in form designer property window.

**Correction:**
On the form, setting the `Border` to `Fixed3D` will remove the sizing grip from the form... UNLESS you have a status strip on the form with a `SizingGrip` set to `true`.
**Solution:** insure that your form's `statusStrip1.SizingGrip = false;`

Answer (score 3):

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.sizegripstyle.aspx

Answer (score 1):

there should be a property of the form called ShowSizeGrip, just set it to False.

Comment: That is a property of the StatusStrip, but not the Form itself.  The Form has a property of SizeGripStyle.